# Retrieve an image from a url and upload it to IPFS

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js, ipfs

I am trying to retrieve an image from a different website, and upload it to IPFS using Next.js. I've set CORS in `next.config.js` to allow the app to retrieve the image, so that seems to be working, and I'm using Axios to store the retrieved file in a `File` object, but the IPFS upload fails:

```
/* pages/test.js */
import Axios from 'axios';
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client';

const client = create('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0');

export default function Test () {

  async function uploadImageToIPFS (url) {
    const file = await Axios
      .get(url, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        new File([response.data], "dummy");
      })
      .catch(ex => {
        console.error(ex);
    });
    try {
      const added = await client.add(
        file,
        {
          progress: (prog) => console.log(`received: ${prog}`)
        }
      )
      const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${added.path}`;
      console.log(url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error uploading file: ', error);
      }
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={() => uploadImageToIPFS('https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E03AQFDEyGQpYnEwA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0/1572360635415?e=1635379200&v=beta&t=W3cLmvalBVyArWAwTnbyeEWrJNbc9eKT7IJgoPhO22w')}>
      Click to upload
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
test.js?142b:31 Error uploading file:  Error: Unexpected input: undefined
    at normaliseInput (normalise-input.js?ce8a:31)
    at normaliseInput.next (<anonymous>)
    at multipartRequest (multipart-request.browser.js?542b:25)
    at addAll (add-all.js?74f2:28)
    at addAll.next (<anonymous>)
    at last (index.js?9975:13)
    at Object.add (add.js?59bb:23)
    at _callee$ (test.js?142b:22)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:294)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:119)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?2297:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?2297:25)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears that `file` is undefined.

Comment: The Axios response.data is already a file, so new File is not needed.

Comment: You should add  a`return` statement in the `axios`'s `then()`, e.g. `return new File([response.data], "dummy");`.

Answer (score 1):

A file is a buffer is the binary result. So the following does what I wanted:

```
const file = await Axios
      .get(tmpNFT.image, { responseType: 'blob' })
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
```